# YARN log aggregation - java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm trying to use YARN log aggregation facility as described [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/), I enabled log aggregation in yarn-site.xml by setting `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` to true. But when I running the aggregation I go the following exception:

```
$ yarn logs -applicationId application_1414083848609_0001
14/10/24 11:08:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/10/24 11:08:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek to negative offset
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.seek(DFSInputStream.java:1381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.BCFile$Reader.<init>(BCFile.java:624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.TFile$Reader.<init>(TFile.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat$LogReader.<init>(AggregatedLogFormat.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.LogCLIHelpers.dumpAllContainersLogs(LogCLIHelpers.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.run(LogsCLI.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.main(LogsCLI.java:199)
```

What's wrong here?